# Can it possible to add Styles to ListView in Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am developing an windows application and in this project i am using ListView Controls to display the Data and i want to change the look of the Listview, so if you have any idea or any use full links then please let me know.

Comment: What aspect of "look" are you interested in? Changing the font? Changing the columns displayed? Have different colors for each row? There's so many ways of changing a "look"...

Comment: I want to change the column header style and want to have different colour for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to draw the style on your own using [Owner Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx)